# Reading In Source Code From .R File, Editing It, Then Saving It

Tags: r, file-io, editing

I'm looking to see if there is a way in R to read in a .R file's source code as text. What I'd like to do is give the path to a .R file, have R grab that R file and return the source code, in text, of that R file.

After that, I plan to make a `gsub` edit on the source code, and then saving the edited text to the same location (which I believe I can do with the `save` function). The `gsub` regular expression is solid (as I wrote the code) and know that will only match what I want it to match and replace.

Naturally, I'm backing up everything before attempting any of this. The part that I am having the most issue with is reading in a .R file's code as text to be edited. I'm also not sure if this would destroy the formatting of the R file, but obviously it would be preferred to not do that. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at `readLines` for reading the .R file, then `write` for writing your output.

Comment: Are you sure that's really necessary? Doing a `gsub` on the sources seems like a pretty extreme way to replace a variable. But if that's what you want to do there's nothing special about an R code file compared to a plain text file so what Benjamin suggest should be straight forward.

Comment: If you had 100 code files and wanted to change something in all of them with a regex, opening each one, searching an replacing in each would be a pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
code <- readLines("<path>")
code_edited <- gsub("foo", "bar", code)
writeLines(code_edited, "<path>")
```

Comment: Thank you! Just the function I was looking for. And I know `gsub` could be dangerous, but I am testing a head of time, keeping everything backed up. I'm confident my method would work.

Comment: I would suggest saving the code with a different name, such as `writeLines(code_edited, "<path2>")`. That way you run no risks :)

Comment: Oh yes, believe me I will backup and test ahead of time. :)